# Python Unittest for function with input file and output file

Tags: python, unit-testing, file, testing

I have a python function which I would like to make an automated test system for it. My function required an input file and will generate output file. I generated lots of test input and output files but its annoying to chech test files one by ones manually. Is there a way to do it in a completely automated way?

I used the following code for checking each test file but it's not automated.

> 

```
import unittest
from mask import load
import io



class TestInterval(unittest.TestCase):
    def testinterval(self):
        input_path = "test10.txt.gz"
        output_path = "test_run.txt"
        column_name = "PCT"
        min_percent = 0.85
        max_depth = 100
        test_out = "test10_out.txt"
        load(column_name, input_path, output_path, min_percent, max_depth)
        self.assertListEqual(
            list(io.open(test_out)),
            list(io.open(output_path)))
        
if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

Comment: Do you mean you want to parameterize the test on the values of `input_path`, `output_path`, and `test_out`, then run the same test on many different triples?

Comment: How can code be "not automated"?  Are you asking about how to generate the test files?  How can anyone help with that if they don't know what the files need to contain?

Comment: No, It's not my question. I already have all test files but I don't want to specify the path in  the code and I was wondering whether unittest can discover my test file itself and how?